# MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file

Tags: c#, ubuntu, sdk

Eu baixei via terminal o SDK e o Runtime da MS. Até então tudo tranquilo, escrevi um programa em C#, tentei rodar e me deparei com a seguinte tela:
[Tela do VS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEkbv.png)
decidi checar se estava tudo ok com a instalação do SDK e o terminal me retornou o seguinte:
[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qC6C.png)
notei que está faltando algo relacionado a esse arquivo Json. Já pesquisei bastante mas eu não faço a mínima ideia de como resolver.

Notas:
Meu código é apenas um simples Hello World!

```
    Using System; 

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class teste
    {
        static void Main(strings[] args){
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

***Estou usando o Ubuntu.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Levando em conta que você quer apenas executar um tradiciona `Hello World!` vamos fazer o seguinte, utilize o comando abaixo para **criar um projeto do tipo console** (executado através do terminal):

```
dotnet new -o MeuProjeto
```

Nota: Caso não utilize o `-o` acompanhado do nome que deseja dar ao projeto, o projeto receberá um nome padrão.

Agora você verá que no diretório em que executou o comando existe agora a pasta do seu projeto e dentro um arquivo *Program.cs* já com o "Hello World!" Dentro.

Este é o início de qualquer projeto com C#. A partir dai você pode transformar este projeto em um projeto web (site, webapp), desktop (programa de área de trabalho ou console) ou talvez apenas bibliotecas de classes para serem usadas em outros projetos.

Se quiser iniciar um projeto com uma estrutura mais desenvolvida pode utilizar os templates que o .NET (framework do C# já oferece). Para isto digite o comando:

```
dotnet new list
```

E receberá a lista completa de todos os templates de projetos que estão instalados na sua máquina.

Comment: Eu consegui criar um template via terminal que gerou o seguinte arquivo: `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>`

Comment: Isso mesmo, conseguiu executar agora?

Comment: Sim, muito obrigado